# Issues with Javascript getting JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

FIXED: I had to upload the files to my server to run ajax

So right now I am trying to pull stock info from a JSON file but nothing is getting pulled up. I alerted ajax.status and 0 showed as result so I think my JSON file is not being read since it I am trying to call a local file in the same directory.

Here is my HTML code: I am supposed to pull up 3 stock quotes.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Stock Quotes</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/clean.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Script 11.x - quote.html -->
    <p>Apple: $<span id="quote"></span></p>
    <p>Google: $<span id="quote"></span></p>
    <p>Facebook: $<span id="quote"></span></p>
    <script src="js/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="js/quote.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS file is supposed to parse my JSON file and then pull each "l" from the object using a loop I have not created yet. I am trying to see if I can pull the first apple stock right now but nothing is coming up.

```
window.onload = function() {
    'use strict';

    // Create the Ajax object:
    var ajax = getXMLHttpRequestObject();

    // Function to be called when the readyState changes:
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {

        // Check the readyState property:
        if (ajax.readyState == 4) {

            // Check the status code:
            if ( (ajax.status >= 200 && ajax.status < 300) 
            || (ajax.status == 304) ) {

                // Parse the response:
                var data = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);

                // Update the page:

                var output = document.getElementById('quote');
                if (output.textContent !== undefined) {
                    output.textContent = data[0].l;
                } else {
                    output.innerText = data[0].l;
                }

            } // End of status IF.

        } // End of readyState IF.

    }; // End of onreadystatechange function.

    // Fetch the initial data:
    ajax.open('GET', 'resources/quote.json', true);
    ajax.send(null);



}; // End of onload anonymous function.
```

This is the JSON file I am parsing.

```
[
    {
        "l": "117.60",
        "l_fix": "117.60",
        "l_cur": "117.60",
        "s": "2",
        "ltt": "4:04PM EST",
        "lt": "Nov 25, 4:04PM EST",
        "lt_dts": "2014-11-25T16:04:18Z",
        "c": "-1.03",
        "c_fix": "-1.03",
        "cp": "-0.86",
        "cp_fix": "-0.86",
        "ccol": "chr",
        "pcls_fix": "118.625",
        "el": "117.73",
        "el_fix": "117.73",
        "el_cur": "117.73",
        "elt": "Nov 25, 7:59PM EST",
        "ec": "+0.13",
        "ec_fix": "0.13",
        "ecp": "0.11",
        "ecp_fix": "0.11",
        "eccol": "chg",
        "div": "0.47",
        "yld": "1.60",
        "eo": "",
        "delay": "",
        "op": "119.07",
        "hi": "119.75",
        "lo": "117.45",
        "vo": "68.84M",
        "avvo": "52.32M",
        "hi52": "119.75",
        "lo52": "70.51",
        "mc": "693.53B",
        "pe": "18.29",
        "fwpe": "",
        "beta": "0.90",
        "eps": "6.43",
        "shares": "5.87B",
        "inst_own": "62%",
        "name": "Apple Inc.",
        "type": "Company"
    },
    {
        "l": "541.08",
        "l_fix": "541.08",
        "l_cur": "541.08",
        "s": "2",
        "ltt": "4:04PM EST",
        "lt": "Nov 25, 4:04PM EST",
        "lt_dts": "2014-11-25T16:04:18Z",
        "c": "+1.81",
        "c_fix": "1.81",
        "cp": "0.34",
        "cp_fix": "0.34",
        "ccol": "chg",
        "pcls_fix": "539.27",
        "el": "541.08",
        "el_fix": "541.08",
        "el_cur": "541.08",
        "elt": "Nov 25, 6:37PM EST",
        "ec": "0.00",
        "ec_fix": "0.00",
        "ecp": "0.00",
        "ecp_fix": "0.00",
        "eccol": "chb",
        "div": "",
        "yld": "",
        "eo": "",
        "delay": "",
        "op": "539.00",
        "hi": "543.98",
        "lo": "538.60",
        "vo": "1.78M",
        "avvo": "1.97M",
        "hi52": "604.83",
        "lo52": "502.80",
        "mc": "369.17B",
        "pe": "27.42",
        "fwpe": "",
        "beta": "",
        "eps": "19.73",
        "shares": "339.34M",
        "inst_own": "69%",
        "name": "Google Inc",
        "type": "Company"
    },
    {
        "l": "75.63",
        "l_fix": "75.63",
        "l_cur": "75.63",
        "s": "2",
        "ltt": "4:04PM EST",
        "lt": "Nov 25, 4:04PM EST",
        "lt_dts": "2014-11-25T16:04:19Z",
        "c": "+1.62",
        "c_fix": "1.62",
        "cp": "2.19",
        "cp_fix": "2.19",
        "ccol": "chg",
        "pcls_fix": "74.01",
        "el": "75.75",
        "el_fix": "75.75",
        "el_cur": "75.75",
        "elt": "Nov 25, 7:59PM EST",
        "ec": "+0.12",
        "ec_fix": "0.12",
        "ecp": "0.16",
        "ecp_fix": "0.16",
        "eccol": "chg",
        "div": "",
        "yld": "",
        "eo": "",
        "delay": "",
        "op": "74.21",
        "hi": "75.74",
        "lo": "74.13",
        "vo": "32.25M",
        "avvo": "38.87M",
        "hi52": "81.16",
        "lo52": "43.55",
        "mc": "206.14B",
        "pe": "71.76",
        "fwpe": "",
        "beta": "",
        "eps": "1.05",
        "shares": "2.04B",
        "inst_own": "69%",
        "name": "Facebook Inc",
        "type": "Company"
    }
]
```

Comment: try to remove `JSON.parse` from `JSON.parse(ajax.responseText)` its already parsed http://jsfiddle.net/7c4k68et/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your data is already parsed as it is received from `.json` file.
Can you try by inspecting the `ajax.responseText`.
Note that JSON.parse accepts the parameter as string. i.e

```
JSON.parse("[{}]");//parsed successfully
JSON.parse([{}]);//error
```

Comment: I found out I am getting ajax.status = 0 so I guess that line of code is not even running. I dont get why I put the JSON file in the same directory called it

Comment: Resource path(resources/quote.json in your case) is resolved with respect to the HTML page path and not the JS file within which it is getting executed.

Comment: I dont know what that means. Resolved? So am I supposed to load the script in html using <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/quote.json"></script>

Comment: You are loading it correctly. what i want to say is browser will try to fetch the 'resource/quote.json' from the directory in which your current html file resides. You may wish to open the debugger and see the network tab to verify which file is getting requested

Comment: So I just used this and deleted the status validation and got something to display. Only my first apple stock shows [ which is the first thing from the json file. var data = ajax.responseText; and using output.textContent = data[0]; But I cant get it to display l

Comment: I suspect you might be getting cached version of quote.json. You can check the response in network debugger tab. If you always want to get it from server you should modify the url param of .open() method to 'resources/quote.json?ck=' + (new Date().getTime()). Also you may check only ajax.status === 200

Comment: I realized ajax.status does not work unless the files are hosted on a server. Once I uploaded it to my server the program worked. I was trying to make it work before loading it. First time using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try parsing the json like this:

`var data = eval('('+ajax.responseText+')');`

Comment: Tried and still does not work, I have a separate JSON file so JSON.parse() should work in any browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading `JSON` file by ajax which will parse your file content into JSON object as a ajax response, so there is no need to again parse this into JSON you can directly use response as JSON object.

Remove below line :

```
 var data = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
```

Use directly `var data = ajax.responseText;`

Comment: I checked ajax.status and I am getting 0.